# How can I work around the inability to save macros in ViEmu?

Tags: vimrc, macro

I would like to be able to save my ViEmu macros between sessions of Visual Studio 2013.  This feature was [requested](http://www.viemu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1248) in 2010 and apparently almost made the cut for ViEmu 2.5:

> I was wondering if there is a way to set a macro in the .viemurc file,
>   so I don't have to redo it every time I start up VS. I know that it
>   can be done in regular Vim via:
>   `:let @s="0ftwwy$bp"`
>   This will set a
>   macro on register 's' for example. Doing the same in .viemurc so far
>   just got me an error message.

> I was indeed planning to add this to ViEmu 2.5, but I've had to drop
>   it or I would never finish it. I will add it in later. ViEmu 2.5 does
>   have multiple-key mappings and a few other exciting features.

As of ViEmu 3.2.1, this feature still does not seem to be implemented.  I tried adding `:let` statements to `_viemurc` and simply got errors.

How might I work around this missing feature?  Never closing Visual Studio is not going to work forever.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with viemu. Does it let you yank to an arbitrary register? If so, you could have a file of your macros and do something like `"sy$` to grab one and `@s` to play it

Comment: It does, and that basically works.  I was considering that solution as somewhat of a last resort; better still would be to have this done automatically on starting the app (and saving macros somewhere automatically as well).  That might be asking a bit much for a "workaround," but one can hope.

Comment: This question appears to be about a proprietary vi emulator embedded in another program. Current consensus is that it is not [considered to be vi](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/7/24) and thus off-topic, but you may want to post a Meta question to discuss that.

Comment: @200_success Thanks for the feedback.  I did check [help/on-topic] before asking and interpreted "specific issues with the Vi and Vim family of editors" to include this type of plugin.  Incidentally, [tag:viemu] is not _solely_ a programmer's plugin in that there is a version for Microsoft Office.

Comment: This being a brand-new site, the help center is still very sketchy because the rules are not set in stone yet. You can play a role in shaping the direction of the site by posting on [meta].

Comment: nvi (at least version 1.81.6) also doesn't let you `:let` a register for later playback. It doesn't have a let command at all, as near as I can tell. If you broaden the question to saving registers in vi family editors that lack the ability to let a register, you might get an answer that works on viemu as well.